# Can python process complex field names in html forms?

Tags: python, html, forms, cherrypy, genshi

In php we can call form fields like

```
<input type="text" name="obj[obj_id][name]" value="val1" />
```

So in request we have multidimensional array.

```
array('obj_id'=> array('name'=> 'val1'))
```

Python(or it depends on framework?) don't understand such fields and in request we have

```
'obj[obj_id][name]' = [val1, val2]
```

I have used before

```
<input type="checkbox" name="obj" value="${json.dumps([name, val1])}" />
```

and to get field content as a python list

```
obj = json.loads(obj)
```

so

```
name, val1 = obj
```

works.

But it is convenient only for checkboxes and not for input text fields.
Is there any solution?

I am using cherrypy 3 with genshi (+ python 3, if that matters)

**UPD**
Have recently noticed, that setting form enctype="multipart/form-data" makes checkboxes with the same names also non-working, so the third code example

```
'obj[obj_id][name]' = [val1, val2]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `$obj_id` doesn't look like Python.

Comment: No, of course. I only meant to ask could we pass multidimensional arrays (or list or dictionaries) through html forms to python?